# selecting images from gallery in dual sim devices

Tags: android

when i selecting image from gallery, Application class object again creating . This problem is occurred in some devices only, I think in dual Sim devices only , in remaining devices its working fine. please tell me why this is happening.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not related to the number of supported SIM cards by Phone. Application object will be created if Android decides to kill the application to gain some memory for current foreground Application. From your question it is not clear whether you are loading Images from your own App or from some other App.

1. If you are using Images from another App may be for displaying those Images Android needs some extra memory therefore it decides to kill your application (and/or some other background App). The Application will be relaunched normally when you come back to your App.
2. If you are loading Images from inside your App and Application is crashing then there is some problem with your code. Try to debug that using logs and update your question with more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. loading Images from inside my App only and activity again created for some images especially in dual Sim devices.

Comment: Are you getting any exception. Put Log_CAT in verbose mode and see if you get some log when it crashes. The App may be crashing in native code. The fact that nothing is being reported in log cat itself indicates that their is a crash somewhere.