# android application get crashed in dual sim android phone

Tags: android

In my application I am using android operating system Camera service to capture image and then I set it to application image view object. Usually it works fine but when ever I try to run my app on dual Sim phone, it get crashed. I am not able to understand what could be the possible reason. Can any one tell me what could be the reason.

I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246873/selecting-images-from-gallery-in-dual-sim-devices) in which there is an explanation. According to that explanation android needs some extra memory to display the image, therefore it decides to kill my application If so then why this problem doesn't occur in other phone and if this is the reason then what is the possible solution.

please help me.

thank you

Comment: I don't think this is camera service problem. Are you by any chance trying to  read the IMEI number from the dual sim phone. On some dual sim phones, this has been known to cause crashes.

Comment: no i didn't read IMEI number. I simply capture the image and store it to a specified location and set it to my image view object that is all I did.

Comment: you have to pst your error log here to identify the exact problem